# window.print in jquery

Tags: css

I have a jquery dialog with scrollable option i want to print the content of the dialog. If I use `window.print()` method it just print the showed content. The remaining scrollable content are unable to print. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: can u post your code??? will be useful

Comment: Isn't it a CSS issue? Do you have a CSS with the `media` attribute set to `print`?

Comment: If you are ok with using jQuery you can use [Print Element](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/printElement)

Comment: Following on from my answer below, it is a CSS issue only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, it's that you have a scrollable `div` of say, 200px in height, yet the content in it is 1000px tall, and you would like all content of the div to be displayed when the page is printed.

If this is correct, what you will need is to specify a stylesheet for use when priting. As an example try adding this to the head of your page:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    #myScrollableDiv {
        overflow: visible;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Depending on the structure of your CSS, you may need to add `!important` flags on each of those statements.

Comment: Glad to help. You may want to consider accepting some answers to your questions as it means people will be more likely to help you in future.